# Powershell: inserting a newline into every 2nd line in a txt file

Tags: powershell

i have to pipe values from an array in powershell to a txt file, but the problem is that these values get typed into the text file without newlines like so:

Value11
Value12
Value21
Value22

I want it to look like this:

Value11
Value12

Value21
Value22

basically separating the text with a newline after every second line. How can I achieve that with powershell?

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-Content -ReadCount 2` to read the file 2 lines at a time, then inject an empty string after each, and write to a new file:

```
Get-Content .\path\to\file.txt -ReadCount 2 |ForEach-Object {
    $_  # This will expand to two lines at a time
    ''  # followed by this empty string
} |Set-Content .\path\to\output.txt
```